# Batch file acceses server without pathd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to acces a couple of servers, find a certain file and copy it to my computer.
 (The inserted path is general. It will look into subfolders also).
The following code can do that if I assign a letter to each server or by using **pushd** command and the computer auto assignes a letter to each server.
BUT how can I do this with the following code without using any letter or assigning new letters, just by the servers name (equivalent to **cd** \192.168.1.153\Contracte)

Code:

```
SET destination=%CD%
cd \\192.168.1.153\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 107501N - 110000N\
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "107720"') do (
cd ..
xcopy "%%a" "%destination%\CtrExtrase\107720NA\" /E /D /Y )
@ECHO ---



pause
```

Comment: `cmd` and its `cd` command cannot set the current directory to a UNC path, it needs a drive, so why not using `pushd`?

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title. Did you mean _access_ or _accesses_?

Answer (score 0):

`CD` doesn't support UNC, has you already notice.

But you don't need to change your current directory at all:

```
SET remotefolder=\\192.168.1.153\Contracte\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 107501N - 110000N\
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir %remotefolder%*107720* /b /s') do (
    xcopy "%%a" "CtrExtrase\107720NA\" /E /D /Y
)
```

Also you may specify your search term in `dir` command without piping to `find`.

Comment: Thank you. It says "Cannot perform a cyclic copy". What happend?

Comment: Not sure. Mine works. Is your `CtrExtrase\107720NA\` writeable?

Comment: yes, it's writeable. I could do it with push and popd but the problem is that if the batch has an error the assigned letters remain and popd doesn't remove them. I need to find an "error handler".

Comment: Make sure you're destination folder and source folders are independent, ie, not child one each other. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959231.aspx

Comment: The search path is on the server. The folder where it copies the results is on my computer. It copies lets say 123N folders content to a new created folder in my pc (same name). Anyway i think i found a way using pathd and popd and adding IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO END and at the :END popd again.

Answer (score 0):

try to map it with net use: `net use s: \\192.168.1.153\Contracte\` and then `cd /d "s:\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 107501N - 110000N\"`

To find free drive letter check this : http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=410

Comment: Tried that but this will be used by multiple users on multiple computers and it is very possible that if I choose a letter that is already in use on some computer and it will return error.